# returning a dataframe as a response to azure function

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I am trying to build an azure function using python. the function takes text as an input and then processes it and returns it as a dataframe. The problem is that Azure function cannot take a data frame as an output. What can i do to pass it as an output while keeping the tabular structure of the dataframe intact.

Comment: Please share the code you currently have. If the requirement is to pass the response in tabular format, why not pass the response as a JSON or even csv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is that Azure function cannot take a data frame as an output.

Yes, AFAIK you cannot, but to achieve this you can format the data into JSON or CSV as @Anupam Chand mentioned.

```
import pandas as p
import logging

import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:

    text =req.params.get('name')
    d = p.DataFrame({'Data': [text], 'Size': [len(text)]})
    res = d.to_json(orient='records')
    print(res)
    return func.HttpResponse(res, mimetype='application/json')
```

[image]
Here, I have hardcoded input you can, take input dynamically.

For csv  modify below lines:

```
res = d.to_csv(index=False)
```

and

```
return func.HttpResponse(res, mimetype='text/csv')
```